# How to extract all the numbers from file and compute the sum of the numbers?

Tags: python, regex, numbers, sum, findall

I will read through and parse a file with text and numbers. I will extract all the numbers in the file and compute the sum of the numbers.

Data Files: http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_361580.txt

My code is:

```
import re

sum = 0

file = open('regex_sum_361580')
for line in file:
    numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    if not numbers:
        continue
    else:
        for number in numbers:
            sum = int(number)

print (sum)
```

Also, is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: you forgot the `.txt` at the end of the filename.

Comment: `for number in numbers: sum = int(number)` is the problem. You wanna compute the _sum_, don't you? And what's the definition of _sum_?

Comment: This code does exactly what I expect it to do. Please explain the difference between what it does, and what you want it to do

Comment: It should be `sum += int(number)`, since you are incrementing the variable

Comment: It would be nice if you could clarify what exactly is not working in your code. Are you getting an error? Is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: Still I get Attribution Error:   Attribute Error: 'module' objects has no attribute 'findall'

Answer (score -1):

you forgot to increment the sum variable, you were just re initializing it and don't use keywords as variable names. Also make a habit of mentioning the mode in which you want to open the file.

```
import re

sum = 0

file = open('regex_sum_361580', 'r')
for line in file:
    numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    if not numbers:
        continue
    else:
        for number in numbers:
            sum += int(number)

print (sum)
```